# Insert data from an existing/non-existing column to another from a calculated mysql result?

Tags: mysql, string, insert

Using the function to split strings: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fullname,  ' ', 1 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) AS firstname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fullname,  ' ', 2 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) AS lastname
FROM users;
```

I get the following resuts:

```
firstname | lastname |

    john      doe

    jane      doe
```

I have the following questions:

1.)How can I insert the values on columns that already exist under the same table?

2.)How can I insert the values on columns that don't exist under the same table?

Of course, the two columns being `firstname | lastname`

Comment: What do you mean by columns that don't exist?  You can't dynamically create columns.  Do you mean where the field for a given row is null?

Comment: Ah, I guess I wasn't thinking straight. I thought it was possible to dynamically create columns for some reason. Would you suggest editing my question for already existing columns?

Comment: I took a shot at what I'm guessing you're trying to do.  All columns have to be defined in the table schema.  You can create a new table using the create table as select ... syntax to create a new table, but not to add columns to an existing table.  If the columns are not defined for the table, you'll need to add them with the alter table add column... statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert these values:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fullname,  ' ', 1 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) AS firstname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( fullname,  ' ', 2 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) AS lastname
FROM users;
```

To update existing values, for the same row:

```
update users
set firstname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,  ' ', 1 ) ,  ' ', -1 ),
   lastname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,  ' ', 2 ) ,  ' ', -1 )
```

To update existing values, but a different row:

```
update users users_a, users users_b
set users_b.firstname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( users_a.fullname,  ' ', 1 ) ,  ' ', -1 ),
    users_b.lastname = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( users_a.fullname,  ' ', 2 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) 
where users_a.??? = users_b.??? /* join condition as appropriate */
```